# SOAP Message Envelope

Tags: java, soap, message

Does anybody know if there is a way using java to pass all the XML content of SOAP Envelope to a String?

Thanks,

Comment: Is your java program the client to a web service or the web service itself?

Comment: It's the client to a webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a bit on what you're using for SOAP and if you want the server or the client to log.

I know that in Axis2 you can use this to get it

```
MessageContext msgContext = MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext();
if (msgContext != null) {
    return msgContext.getEnvelope().getBody().toString();
}
```